# Is Linux Kernel fully Namespace-aware now?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-namespaces

I am reading the book Professional Linux Kernel Architecture which comes out in 2008.
In the page 49, talking about Process Management and Scheduling,

> Namespaces are currently still marked as experimental in the standard
>   kernel, and development  to make all parts of the kernel fully
>   namespace-aware are still going on.

My question is : Is namespace in standard kernel yet?

Comment: The Linux kernel implements [six different kinds of namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/).

Comment: Yes, it is part of std kernel. i think Professional Linux Kernel Architecture talks about 2.6.x kernels